# Export WSO2 ESB's data source

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can i export data source from WSO2 ESB, and import them into another ESB service ?

If it is couldn't, how can I copy data source from on ESB service to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined your data sources within ESB, these are saved in the local registry. You can download this registry file by searching from registry. Here is the location in which your defined data source configurations are saved in the ESB

**/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/TestDataSource**

I think you can just download the file from this location (from ESB management console) and just copy paste the content to the new configuration.

Comment: I was configure data sources in the management console, using Home  > Configure > Data Sources.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, you want to migrate WSO2 ESB artifacts to another ESB. This is not supported out of the box, and you will have to implement your own tools

Comment: Hi Samisa,
Thanks your response.

If you have the example of implement my own tools?

Answer (score 0):

When migrating the artifacts stored in registry (i.e endpoints,local entries, dynamic sequences and data sources and  etc) you can use WSO2 G-Reg's check in client tool to checkout a dump from one ESB and checkin that to another ESB. Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Check-in+Client. i.e you can checkout the whole local registry of ESB running on port 9443 as follows.

```
checkin-client.sh co https://IP-ADD:9443/registry/ -u admin -p admin_pw -f remote.dump
```

and checkin the dump to an ESB on port 9444 as follows

```
checkin-client.sh ci https://IP-ADD:9444/registry/ -u admin -p admin_pw -f remote.dump
```